Unable to connect to remote server on normal boot
I am a newbie in linux. I purchased a remote baremetal server with Archlinux 9 running on it.  I created a bridge network for the KVM VMs to connect to the external network using cockpit console. Next, I created a bridge network using virt manager virbr0 and by mistake, I made this as the master. This made me lose the network access to the server. How can I recover the network. I tried to login using the recovery mode, using chroot and tried to delete the virbr0.nmconnection and the bridge0.nmconnection files, but still I don't have access in the normal mode. I edited the enp2s0.nmconnection file but still server is unreachable. My enp2s0.nmconnection looks like this:
[connection]
id=enp2s0
uuid=923c1611-a07a-4a22-ae70-85b898e22ebd
type=ethernet

[ethernet]
mac-address=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
permissions=

[ipv4]
address1=192.168.255.xxx/24
address2=89.163.xxx.xxx/23

Is there any way to recover the network? I can't run NetworkManager in the chroot environment.

do you have console access to this system otherwise No

No I don't, unfortunately

setup you network by hand with ifconfig then

Hi @Simson, can you give me an example. Will it run in chroot environment
